# string with valid characters only without regex

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have a string containing "hello, world!" and another one with "hello world", I want my function to return false for the first and trye for the second, by basically checking it against an array of valid characters, for example a-z.

Problems is I do NOT want to use a regex. I could use .indexOf but it only works for ONE character.

Any way to do this, possibly in a non-blocking way (using node.js)?

Thanks in advance.

In PHP, I used to do something similar:

```
$sUser = 'my_username01'; 
$aValid = array('-', '_'); 

if(!ctype_alnum(str_replace($aValid, '', $sUser))) { 
  echo 'Your username is not properly formatted.'; 
}
```

Comment: Why no RegEx? (curious)

Comment: ... Why would you not want to use regex for this? The only other option I see is declaring an array of characters, iterate over them, and do an ``indexOf`` for each of them.

Comment: ok ok we have to do, "Any way to do this"?

Comment: because regexes suck :D

Comment: A lot of times regexes do suck. In this case, on the other hand, they really seem like the best option.

Comment: Regular expressions do *not* 'suck' when they're used appropriately; in many cases they're the best tool for the job, as opposed to the potential *other* solutions which, in this case, is likely to involve quite a lot of unnecessary work to approximate the same (*faster*, and *more-efficient*) solution offered by the correct use of a regular expression.

Comment: Regexes are the best way to solve this problem.  Blanket statements like that are not going to get you very far.

Answer (score 1):

```
function hasBadChars(s) {
    var badChars = ['!'],
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
        if (badChars.indexOf(s[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(hasBadChars('Hello world!'));
```